# Application for fullscreen note taking with Wacom tablet

Tags: software-recommendation, wacom, graphics-tablet

I have a Wacom tablet and a netbook, I would like to use both as a paper replacement for taking notes. Is there some note taking application that runs in full screen and lets you save the images/vector images in a reasonable format?

Comment: I just build something simple myself. If anyone still knows something, I'll be happy to hear it.

Comment: For the record, I'm interested to know what you came up with!

Comment: I build [jscribble](https://github.com/martin-ueding/jscribble), though I did not put more work into it after learning about Xournal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xournal lets you draw in full-screen mode, has pressure sensitivity settings and can export to pdf (only, it seems). I haven't used it for note taking, only to annotate pdf articles. There seems to be no automatic hand-writing to text conversion.

Comment: I will definitly try it out, maybe it is better than my own application.

Comment: Okay, this program is very nice, but it is paper-format focused and not screen-format focused. Other than that it has many interesting features.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [Write](http://www.styluslabs.com/) by Stylus Labs could suit your needs. I just posted a recommendation for this software in an answer to another question (someone who was looking for a note taking app, but not necessarily a full-screen one).

Write has infinite scroll, so you're not limited by paper size, just like you wanted. Unfortunately, I have I haven't tried it myself yet. I just downloaded it and am about to use it for the first time, and I will update my answer after using it.

To install dependencies: `sudo apt-get install libqt5widgets5 libqt5network5 libqt5svg5`

Comment: Note: I have been unable to get this to work on Ubuntu 16.04, even after installing all the dependencies that 16.04 lacks and changing my library paths and such. In particular, I couldn't get it to recognize the newer version of QT I added. If you're better at building from source than I am, you could probably make it work, but if not, you will need 17.04 and up.